# How to call api on recyclerview scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am doing a project where i have to call an api on scolling event of recyclerview to get new set of question list from server.

Please guide me , I will be thankful to you.

Comment: How many items you have loaded initially??

Comment: thanks for your time , i have added 10 items initially

Answer (score 0):

For pagination in recyclerview use addOnScrollListener() method, you will get the answer here [How to call api on recyclerview scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405799/how-to-call-api-on-recyclerview-scrolling/37407365#37407365)

Comment: Please don't copy answers from duplicate questions. Link to the question/answer instead.